# Recursion-free expansion of variadic template into array access

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the follow non-type variadic template function:

```cpp
template <typename dummy = void>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
}

template <size_t OFF, size_t... OFFs>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
    p[OFF] = 1;
    write_at_offsets<OFFs...>(p);
}
```

It uses the recursive approach to write a 1 at the offsets specified in the template parameter pack.

Can this be written succinctly without using recursion in C++11, e.g., by expanding the whole pack in one shot?

Answer (score 5):

You can use *fold* expressions (since c++17), passing offsets in `index_sequence`:

```
template<size_t ... Indices>
void foo(std::index_sequence<Indices...>,volatile char* p){
    ( (p[Indices] = 1),... );
}

int main(){
    char* p = new char[3];
    foo(std::index_sequence<0,1,2>(),p);
```

With C++11 created fake array filled by 0 with using comma expression `(Calculation,0)`:

```
template<size_t ... Indices>
void foo(char* p, const int val){
    int fake[] = { (p[Indices] = val,0)... };
    // cast fake to void to prevent compiler warning present
}

int main(){
    char* p = new char[3];
    foo<0,1,2>(p,48);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work without the `std::index_sequence` as well? (I mean - to resemble OPs code closer.) I fiddled with your example: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9000c713c15a366)

Comment: @Scheff Nice version :), you are right, index_sequence is in some way redundant in my example.

Comment: Yes, this is what I use in C++17, but here I'm limited to C++11.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Added C++11 version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using only C++11 constructs.

```
template <size_t... OFFs>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
    dummyfunc((p[OFFs] = 1, 0) ...) ;  
}
```

`dummyfunc` is any old variadic function that ignores its arguments.

Not passing the result of assignment directly because using the result of assignment to a volatile variable is now deprecated (though it wasn't in C++11).

Comment: Notice than order of evaluation is then unspecified and for from left to right.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In simple case like this, you might use regular loop:

```
template <std::size_t... OFFs>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
    for (std::size_t i : {OFFs}) {
        p[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Else there are tricks in C++11/C++14 to simulate some fold expression of C++17:

```
template <std::size_t... OFFs>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
    const int dummy[] = {0, (p[OFFs] = 1, 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
}
```

whereas C++17 would simply be

```
template <std::size_t... OFFs>
void write_at_offsets(volatile char *p) {
    (p[OFFs] = 1, ...);
}
```